# Query in CodeIgniter for most purchased data

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

> transaction table
>   Title:
>   001. PHP CookBook
>   002. C++ Beginner
>   003. Advanced Java
>   004. PHP CookBook
>   005. PHP CookBook
>   006. Advanced Java

What I want to create is a list of the most purchased book from the **Transaction** table as shown above and generate a list like this:

> Most purchased:
>
> 1. PHP CookBook
> 2. Advanced Java
> 3. C++ Beginner

I work using **PHP CI** and what I've done is like this:

```
$this->db->select('Title');
$this->db->from('transaction');
$this->db->count('Title AS TitleCount');
$this->db->group_by('AssetTitle');
$this->db->order_by('TitleCount','ASC');
$this->db->limit(4);
$temp = $this->db->get();
$temp->num_rows();
return $temp->result_array();
```

But the result wasn't like as I wanted. The **COUNT** is not recognized by CodeIgniter.
I don't quite understand about query, so maybe if there someone out there who can help me with this query, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try:  `$this->db->order_by('count(*)','ASC');`

Comment: It works! Only need to replace the `ASC` into `DESC`. Thanks! @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('Title,count(Title) AS TitleCount',FALSE);
$this->db->from('transaction');
$this->db->group_by('AssetTitle');
$this->db->order_by('TitleCount','ASC');
$this->db->limit(4);
```

try this

Comment: You may need to add a second parameter of `FALSE` to the select. CodeIgniter will add backticks around things such as `count(Title)`.